# Volley Post Request ClientError

Tags: android, post, request, android-volley

I'm trying to send a POST Request with Volley to my server but it didnt work.
My GET-Requests are working fine and i also used postman to check if my rest service at the server works correctly.

I'm always getting a ClientError:

```
com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:190)
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)
```

I saw many different solutions here, but none of them worked out for my problem.
My StringRequest looks like this:

```
                                StringRequest addOrder = new StringRequest(
                                        Request.Method.POST,
                                        "http://myservice/rest/order",
                                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                String success =  "DONE";
                                            }
                                        },
                                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                String test = error.toString();
                                                //Log.e("Rest Response", error.toString());
                                            }
                                        })
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public String getBodyContentType() {
                                        return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public byte[] getBody() {
                                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                        try{
                                            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
                                            oos.writeObject(clickedCocktail);
                                            oos.flush();
                                        }
                                        catch(IOException ioe){
                                            //Do Stuff by Exception
                                            String exStr = ioe.getMessage();
                                        }
                                        return bos.toByteArray();
                                    }
                                };
                                requestQueue.add(addOrder);
                            }
```